# Wordpress + nginx infinite redirect loop

Tags: nginx, web-server, wordpress

I'm having problems with a wordpress site to enter the admin area.

If I enter with:
http://www.beshan.com/wp-admin/

I get an infinite redirect loop but if I enter with:

http://www.beshan.com/wp-admin/index.php

it works

My client's server is a centos linux + nginx

the nginx.conf:

```
user  www www;
worker_processes 8;
error_log  logs/nginx_error.log  crit;
#pid        /usr/local/webserver/nginx/nginx.pid;

#Specifies the value for maximum file descriptors that can be opened by this process. 
worker_rlimit_nofile 51200;
events 
{
  use epoll;
  worker_connections 51200;
}

http 
{
  include       mime.types;
  default_type  application/octet-stream;
  #charset  gb2312;
  server_names_hash_bucket_size 128;
  client_header_buffer_size 32k;
  large_client_header_buffers 4 32k;
  client_max_body_size 8m;

  sendfile on;
  tcp_nopush     on;

  keepalive_timeout 60;

  tcp_nodelay on;
  server_tokens off;

  fastcgi_connect_timeout 300;
  fastcgi_send_timeout 300;
  fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
  fastcgi_buffer_size 64k;
  fastcgi_buffers 4 64k;
  fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 128k;
  fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 128k;

  gzip on;
  gzip_min_length  1k;
  gzip_buffers     4 16k;
  gzip_http_version 1.0;
  gzip_comp_level 2;
  gzip_types       text/plain application/x-javascript text/css application/xml;
  gzip_vary on;

  #limit_zone  crawler  $binary_remote_addr  10m;

  server
  {
    listen       80;
    server_name  www.beshan.com;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;
    root  /usr/local/nginx/htdocs/beshan.com/www/;

    #limit_conn   crawler  20;    

    location / {
        index  index.php;
        # If file not found, redirect to Zend handling, we can remove the (if) here and go directly rewrite
        if (!-f $request_filename){
        rewrite ^/(.+)$ /index.php?$1& last;
        }
    }
    location ~* ^.+\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|pdf|png|css)$ {
      access_log   off;
      expires      7d;
    }
    location ~ .*\.php?$ {
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

#    location ~ .*\.(php|php5)?$
#    {      
#      #fastcgi_pass  unix:/tmp/php-cgi.sock;
#      fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
#      fastcgi_index index.php;
#      include fcgi.conf;
#    }
#    
#    location ~ .*\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|bmp|swf)$
#    {
#      expires      30d;
#    }
#
#    location ~ .*\.(js|css)?$
#    {
#      expires      7d;
#    }    

    log_format  access  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
              '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
              '"$http_user_agent" $http_x_forwarded_for';
    access_log  logs/access.log  access;
  }
}
```

In chrome developer tools->network i can see a lot of 302 redirects, 25 aprox before show the error message.

Is it something bad configured in nginx? how can i solve it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the problem:

```
        if (!-f $request_filename){
        rewrite ^/(.+)$ /index.php?$1& last;
        }
```

This is one of the [most common nginx misconfigurations](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/).

Replace these three lines with [`try_files`](http://nginx.org/r/try_files):

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
```

See also the [WordPress wiki entry on nginx](http://codex.wordpress.org/Nginx).

(BTW, your .htaccess does nothing, since you are not using Apache.)

Comment: Adding `$uri/` to my try files did the trick for me. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In the sites-enabled folder you will need to end the configuration for your site and add the multisite redirection rules. For Ubuntu 14.04 you will be able to find the path under /etc/nginx/sites-available

Add the following block in your server block and you should be able to avoid the infinite redirection loop.

```
#Rewrite multisite '.../wp-.*' and '.../*.php'.
if (!-e $request_filename) {
    rewrite /wp-admin$ $scheme://$host$uri/ permanent;
    rewrite ^/[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+(/wp-.*) $1 last;
    rewrite ^/[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+(/.*\.php)$ $1 last;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. Added to nginx domain config:

```
#Rewrite multisite '.../wp-.*' and '.../*.php'.
if (!-e $request_filename) {
    rewrite /wp-admin$ $scheme://$host$uri/ permanent;
    rewrite ^/[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+(/wp-.*) $1 last;
    rewrite ^/[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+(/.*\.php)$ $1 last;
}
```